# Teamcity trigger by user

Tags: teamcity

Is it possible to exclude from **Teamcity** trigger pushes by certain git user?

e.g. there are three users who push in master branch, but i don't need to run test task when it is a push from me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to specify ["trigger rules"](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-buildTriggerRules) to exclude/include certain VCS users:

> VCS_username- if specified, limits the rule only to the changes made by a user with the corresponding VCS username.

Just enter all rules you want when editing trigger (in my case it's the parameter `%VCSTriggerRules%`):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can edit Team City VCS Trigger to achieve this.
In trigger edit window you will see VCS Trigger rules section. There you can add a rule and exclude commits by username, comment or even files.
See documentation here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-buildTriggerRules

Answer (score 0):

`-:user=example_user:**`

This will exclude all changes made by username `example_user`. I was trying for a while without the wildcard and it wasn't working for me.